# PCA plots in R kernel when using Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, pca

I want to see the plots generated by PCA function from FactoMineR package when I use the R kernel of Jupyter Notebook. In RStudio they appear on the plot part. Nevertheless I can't open them here.

Comment: I share the exact same question as you too, except I'm using SensoMineR (but both are related), my question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972807/plot-generated-from-r-library-is-not-showing-in-r-jupyter-notebook . Unfortunately, I'm as clueless as you are, and as much in need of help!

Comment: A workaround solution for my problem can be found on Github after I posted there: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/545 maybe it can work for you!

Comment: Amazing! Ill check it out, been 8 months haha

Answer (score 1):

You should perform PCA but don't draw the graphs, using the argument `graph=FALSE`, and then you draw the graph with the plot function:

```
data(decathlon)
res <- PCA(decathlon,quanti.sup=11:12, quali.sup=13, graph=FALSE)
plot(res, choix="ind")
plot(res, choix="var")
```