# Plot generated from R library is not showing in R Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am using the [SensoMineR package `coltable` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SensoMineR/versions/1.23/topics/coltable) to generate a heatmap like plot of sensory data I've analyzed.

The problem I'm facing is that while executing this function in the R terminal will display the figure, executing this function in the R Jupyter notebook does not display the figure. The figure is not showing in Jupyter.

The documentation I've linked above contains example code which easily emulates plot generation. Apart from my own analysis code, this example code also does not work in my Jupyter notebook.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to overcome this problem please.

Comment: Workaround solution to this problem can be found here: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/545